# How can I mock a class that implements the Iterator interface using PHPUnit?

Tags: php, iterator, mocking, phpunit

How can I mock a dependency for my class that implements the [`Iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) interface in a robust manner?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's a couple of existing solutions to this problem online already but all of the ones I've seen share a similar weakness: they rely on `->expects($this->at(n))`. The 'expects at' function in PHPUnit has slightly odd behaviour in that the counter is for every method call to the mock. This means that if you have method calls to your iterator outside of a straight forward foreach you have to adjust your iterator mock.

The solution to this is to create an object holding the basic iterator data (source array and position) and pass that into `returnCallback` closures. Because it's passed by reference the object is kept up to date between calls so we can mock each method to simulate a simple iterator. Now we can use the iterator mock as normal without having to worry about a rigid call order.

Sample method below that you can use to setup an iterator mock:

```
/**
 * Setup methods required to mock an iterator
 *
 * @param PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject $iteratorMock The mock to attach the iterator methods to
 * @param array $items The mock data we're going to use with the iterator
 * @return PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject The iterator mock
 */
public function mockIterator(PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject $iteratorMock, array $items)
{
    $iteratorData = new \stdClass();
    $iteratorData->array = $items;
    $iteratorData->position = 0;

    $iteratorMock->expects($this->any())
                 ->method('rewind')
                 ->will(
                     $this->returnCallback(
                         function() use ($iteratorData) {
                             $iteratorData->position = 0;
                         }
                     )
                 );

    $iteratorMock->expects($this->any())
                 ->method('current')
                 ->will(
                     $this->returnCallback(
                         function() use ($iteratorData) {
                             return $iteratorData->array[$iteratorData->position];
                         }
                     )
                 );

    $iteratorMock->expects($this->any())
                 ->method('key')
                 ->will(
                     $this->returnCallback(
                         function() use ($iteratorData) {
                             return $iteratorData->position;
                         }
                     )
                 );

    $iteratorMock->expects($this->any())
                 ->method('next')
                 ->will(
                     $this->returnCallback(
                         function() use ($iteratorData) {
                             $iteratorData->position++;
                         }
                     )
                 );

    $iteratorMock->expects($this->any())
                 ->method('valid')
                 ->will(
                     $this->returnCallback(
                         function() use ($iteratorData) {
                             return isset($iteratorData->array[$iteratorData->position]);
                         }
                     )
                 );

    $iteratorMock->expects($this->any())
                 ->method('count')
                 ->will(
                     $this->returnCallback(
                         function() use ($iteratorData) {
                             return sizeof($iteratorData->array);
                         }
                     )
                 );

    return $iteratorMock;
}
```

Comment: I'm posting a solution to a problem I encountered. Since I don't have a blog I put it here. I assume it's a valid way to use SO since there's a checkbox to do it when you post a question :)

Comment: Nice reusable solution!

Comment: nice! I just changed `sizeof()` to `count()`

Comment: Coming back to this question (because I've noticed I keep getting points from it) with a couple of years more unit testing experience under my belt, I'd now ask if you really need to mock out that custom iterator. It's worth thinking how much benefit you're going to get, and how much complexity you'll add to your test, by mocking stuff out. 

I'd like to give two years ago me the benefit of the doubt and assume I had a good reason for this mock, but I've got a feeling that really I'd've been better served just using the real class.

Answer (score 6):

If you just need to test against a generic iterator, then PHP (in the SPL extension - which can't be turned off in PHP > 5.3) has built in array wrappers that implement Iterable: [SPL Iterators](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php). e.g.

```
$mock_iterator = new \ArrayIterator($items);
$test_class->methodExpectingGenericIterator($mock_iterator);
$resulting_data = $mock_iterator->getArrayCopy();
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution which combines the best of both worlds, using an `ArrayIterator` internally:

#### With `phpunit/phpunit` mocking facilities

```
/**
 * @return \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject|SomeIterator
 */
private function createSomeIteratorDouble(array $items = []): SomeIterator
{
    $someIterator = $this->createMock(SomeIterator::class);

    $iterator = new \ArrayIterator($items);

    $someIterator
        ->method('rewind')
        ->willReturnCallback(function () use ($iterator): void {
            $iterator->rewind();
        });

    $someIterator
        ->method('current')
        ->willReturnCallback(function () use ($iterator) {
            return $iterator->current();
        });

    $someIterator
        ->method('key')
        ->willReturnCallback(function () use ($iterator) {
            return $iterator->key();
        });

    $someIterator
        ->method('next')
        ->willReturnCallback(function () use ($iterator): void {
            $iterator->next();
        });

    $someIterator
        ->method('valid')
        ->willReturnCallback(function () use ($iterator): bool {
            return $iterator->valid();
        });

    return $someIterator;
}
```

#### With `phpspec/prophecy`

```
/**
 * @return \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject|SomeIterator
 */
private function createSomeIteratorDouble(array $items = []): SomeIterator
{
    $someIterator = $this->prophesize(\ArrayIterator::class);

    $iterator = new \ArrayIterator($items);

    $someIterator
        ->rewind()
        ->will(function () use ($iterator): void {
            $iterator->rewind();
        });

    $someIterator
        ->current()
        ->will(function () use ($iterator) {
            return $iterator->current();
        });

    $someIterator
        ->key()
        ->will(function () use ($iterator) {
            return $iterator->key();
        });

    $someIterator
        ->next()
        ->will(function () use ($iterator): void {
            $iterator->next();
        });

    $someIterator
        ->valid()
        ->will(function () use ($iterator): bool {
            return $iterator->valid();
        });

    return $someIterator->reveal();
}
```

Comment: Why do people bother with `->expects($this->any())`, it's like THIS MUST HAPPEN, but zero, one or many times, which is 100% of the Venn diagram of possibilities, right?

Comment: @gingerCodeNinja I wouldn’t write test doubles like this anymore, I‘ll update later when at a computer.

Comment: Yeh, just noticed that was a super old answer, all good. (I still see people doing it though, which is odd - I need to ask them why when I catch it next).

Comment: @gingerCodeNinja Adjusted my answer!

Comment: @gingerCodeNinja The `->expects($this->any())` is not there just to test if it is being called 'any' number of times. It's there also to let whoever is checking the tests to explicitly know that a particular function does not have any restriction on the number of times it'll be called. Its useful in TDD.

In the case of this iterator mock, it's not needed since it'll only be used as a sample.

Comment: @BlackPanther I'd imagine in most cases people use 'any' (0 or more), implicit is sufficient though. Alternatively, rather than programmatically adding $this->any/self::any, just a PHP comment, if it's for someone reading the test.